# cells in a longtable spanning multiple pages?

Tags: longtable

I have a longtable with three columns of text.  The first is a state, the second is a year, and the third is some text from a state law.

My problem is that, for some states, the text from the state law is really, really long and wouldn't fit on one just one page.  Thus, the text for those states gets cut off in the PDF when I compile (i.e., it doesn't appear anywhere in the document). But what I wish I could do is have all the text appear, with the offending rows spanning two pages.  Is there a way to do this, or are there any suggested alternatives?

[Note: this issues comes up regardless of whether I have the table in portrait or landscape.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! As far as I know, it is not possible. You'll have to break the text manually.

Comment: almost always in such cases it is better to set that as a list rather than a table, list items break naturally, and you can set the state and year as the item label

Comment: I would use hyperlinks (appendices) for the full text, and just put the titles in the longtable.